# Where can I download org.eclipse.higgins:higgins:1.0.1

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to update our higgins dependency from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1. As 1.0.1 uses apache commons logging.
I have the following dependency in our project

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.higgins</groupId>
        <artifactId>higgins</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

The above dependency comes from our private repository. Now I am looking for 1.0.1 so as to remove our dependency on log4j. But I am not able to find the 1.0.1 version of the above artifact.

I found the following url that says that higgins 1.0.1 was released, but I am not able to find the jar.
https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.higgins/releases/1.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this page

https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.higgins/downloads

Download link navigates to

https://www.eclipse.org/projects/archives.php

The page info says:

> You are seeing this because the project you were looking for has been archived. When projects are archived their data(downloads, source and website), is collected into a single tar.gz file.

So, **this project is archived**, this because no download links are present for jars.

I've tried to find the `tar.gz` with the project sources, but there is no link on the UI.

But I've tried to see how other links look and changed the project name to `higgins`.

So I've found the working link

http://archive.eclipse.org/archived_projects/higgins.tgz

The file is about 3GB, but potentially you are able to download it and build the latest version from sources (or the 1.0.1 jar is already in `higgins.tgz`).

After you'll get the jar, you'll have to add it to some maven repository as a 3-rd party jar.

https://www.google.com/amp/s/roufid.com/3-ways-to-add-local-jar-to-maven-project/amp/